# display multilevel database driven menu in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a database driven Multilevel menu and below is what I have tried so far, but I am not getting the result as desired. Can any one help me to fix this. the output I am getting is only the main menu with parent id as 0, but not the sub menu items.

```
<?php
include('system/connection.php');
?>
<?php

//select all rows from the main_menu table
$q = "SELECT * FROM catelogue WHERE cat_visibility = '1'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

echo "<ul class='dropdown'>";
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    if ($rows['cat_parentid'] == 0) {
        echo "<li><a href='#'>" . $rows['cat_name'] . "</a>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($rows as $item) {
            if ($item['cat_parentid'] == $rows['cat_id']) {
                echo "<li><a href='#'>" . $item['cat_name'] . "</a>";
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

My Database structure is

```
-----------------------------------------
| cat_id   | cat_name    | cat_parentid |
-----------------------------------------
|  1       |  Home       |  0           |
|  2       |  About      |  0           |
|  3       |  Contact    |  0           |
|  4       |  History    |  2           |
|  5       |  Services   |  2           |
-----------------------------------------
```

Desired Output I want:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>About</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>History</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));` see if your query is failing.

Comment: you're not echoing `$id = $rows['cat_id'];` nor using `$id` anywhere else.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  no its not failing. i am getting the output but only the main menu items not the sub menus

Comment: Instead of `if($item['cat_parentid'] == $rows['cat_id']){` try `if($item['cat_parentid'] == $id){` since you were using `$id = $rows['cat_id'];` but have removed it in an edit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes but its of no use, if i remove it also it makes no difference. I tried that too. then i changed it to if($item['cat_parentid'] == $rows['cat_id']){

Comment: plus your `<ul>` and `<li>` aren't properly formatted. Did you [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910284/display-multilevel-database-driven-menu-in-php#comment47942762_29910284)

Comment: It will help if you provide an example of the input - in an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be nice. Also show what you want to see as the output.

Comment: @RyanVincent  I hav provided you the SQL database structure and the desired output. Please see if you can figure out the problem. Thanks

Comment: I have tried to make the code easier to understand by including more comments and naming things more appropriately. I hope it helps you to make it do what you want. I have tested it on more 'nested menus'. The generated code has passed HTML validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution.

The code is fully commented.

There are two useful checks in the `processMenuEntry` routine that can conveniently be done so that you can decide if you want different actions to happen.

- Check whether the 'current' 'entry' is the 'root' node.

  *`$isRoot = $currentEntry['cat_id'] == 0; // do 'First time' processing`*
- Check whether the current 'entry' has a 'submenu'.

  *`if (!empty($subMenu)) { ...`*

[Q29910284-display-multilevel-database-driven-menu.php](http://pastebin.com/DBYhrwWs)

The code:

Database connection:

```
$DB_HOST     = "localhost";
$DB_USER     = "test";
$DB_PASSWORD = "test";
$DB_TO_USE   = "testmysql";

$dbc = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_TO_USE);
```

Submenu Query:

```
/** -----------------------------------------------------------------
 * Select all the menu entries for a given entry Id
 *
 * Note: it is safe to do 'parameter substitution' rather than using
 *       'prepared queries' with placeholders as this 'entry Id' never
 *       comes from an external source.
 *
 * @param mysqli $dbc
 * @param integer $currentEntryId
 * @return array of menu entries
 */
function selectSubMenu($currentEntryId, $dbc)
{
    $sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_parent_id
                   FROM catalogue
                   WHERE cat_parent_id = {$currentEntryId}
                   ORDER BY cat_id";
    $resultSet = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
    return $resultSet->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Process Current Menu Entry:

```
/** --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Process the current menu enty - it will return a complete menu as HTML
 *
 * These needs to know whether the current entry has a submenu and
 * will therefore need to generate an 'unordered list' for the current entry.
 *
 * Alas, it also has to not display the 'list item text' for the  'root' entry
 * but process the 'submenu'.
 * This complicates the <li> current entry text generation slightly.
 *
 * @param array $currentEntry - one row
 * @param array $subMenu - many rows - may be empty
 * @param mysqli $dbc - database connection
 * @return string - the HTML for the menu
 */
function processMenuEntry($currentEntry, array $subMenu, $dbc)  {
    $outMenu = '';
    $isRoot = $currentEntry['cat_id'] == 0; // do 'First time' processing

    // display the current entry text as a 'list item'
    $outMenu .= !$isRoot ? "<li><a href='#'>" . $currentEntry['cat_name'] . "</a>" : '';

    // does it have a submenu...
    if (!empty($subMenu)) { // we need to add a complete submenu of <ul> ... </ul>

        // Start of the submenu as an unordered list -- decide what is required
        if ($isRoot) {
            $outMenu .= '<ul class="dropdown">';
        }
        else {
            $outMenu .= '<ul>';
        }

        // Display each entry of the submenu as a 'list item' 
        foreach ($subMenu as $submenuEntry) {
            $outMenu .= processMenuEntry($submenuEntry,
                                    selectSubMenu($submenuEntry['cat_id'], $dbc),
                                    $dbc);
        }

        // close the current submenu - terminate the unordered list
        $outMenu .= '</ul>';
    }

    // terminate the current list item
    $outMenu .= !$isRoot ? '</li>' : '';
    return $outMenu;
};
```

Process all the menu entries:

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Process all the menu entries
 *
 * We need a complete menu 'tree' that includes a 'root' which is not provided
 * in the database. I think it should be. Whatever, i need one.
 *
 * Initializing a 'tree walk' i always find 'interesting' ;-/
 */
$root = array('cat_id' => 0, 'cat_name' => '', 'cat_parent_id' => 0);

// build the output menu
$outMenu = processMenuEntry($root,
                           selectSubMenu($root['cat_id'], $dbc),
                           $dbc);

// wrap it in a <div>
$htmlMenu = '<div style="border: 1px solid red">'
            . $outMenu
            .'</div>';
?>
```

Output the generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Recursive Menu Builder</title>
</head>
<body>
<?= $htmlMenu ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The generated HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <title>Test Recursive Menu Builder
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
        <a href='#'>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href='#'>About</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
          <a href='#'>History</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a href='#'>Services</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href='#'>Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code applies class to all the `<ul class="dropdown">` but i want it in the starting `<ul>` tag only

Comment: @Kumarjit, i did something about it :)

Comment: yes but it still applying the class on the sub menus also

Comment: @Kumarjit, I deliberately put them there. Sorry. Code changed to only add it to the outer 'unordered list'.

Comment: @Kumarjit, was fun to do - I learn a lot from doing these problems. Glad you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

What you call `$rows` is actually one row. Then, in the `foreach ($rows as $item)` loop, it iterates through the columns of this row. So, there is no `$item['cat_parentid']`. Try to see the output of the `$rows` and `$item` with `var_dump()`.

A draft idea of one possible solution that comes to my mind is to first iterate through the result rows and save the sub items in a parent item (note: some array initializations would have to be added here):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $menuItems[$row['cat_id']] = $row;

    $parentId = $row['cat_parentid'];
    $menuItems[$parentId]['sub_items'][] = $row['cat_id'];
}
```

And then iterate through the `$menuItems` array generating output, [recursion](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-recursive-function-example-factorial-numbers) would be great for this.

Also, ordering the sql results would be beneficial, to be sure that top menu items come first:

```
"SELECT * FROM catelogue WHERE cat_visibility = '1' ORDER BY cat_parentid ASC";
```

Comment: Updated my answer with a draft of one possible way to go.

Comment: I want my top `<ul>`  to have a  `class="dropdown"`  in it. Is it possible in recursive function?

Comment: @Kumarjit: Sure, why not? Extend the recursive function with a `$counter`, and when it calls itself, add the variable: `recursiveFunction($content, $counter+1)`. When `$counter = 0`, add the class.

Comment: @Mave I don't know how to do that. Can you please show me. That will be a great help. Thanks

Comment: @Mave Yes i got some code from internet, but the problem in that is if i put  ` <ul> class ` to the top menu items, it also applies to sub menus as well.

Comment: @Kumarjit Create a new question, and link me to it ;-).